# How to debug jest test with code maps

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I got a failing javascript jest test on my hands and so, I have used the usual stuff to debug:
    node-debug --nodejs --harmony ./node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js --runInBand

So, it actually works but with all the babel-jest black magic going behind the scene, I cannot get to see the original code and to get the debugger to navigate through it properly. I only get one of those horrible one-liners we all hate, or sometimes get stuck in the calling function in the debugger (tried chrome dev tools and visual studio code).
So, is there a way to generate a usable js map and use it to debug jest test?
Do I have to navigate only by watching the call stack and by guessing where I am in my piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is already quite old, so much has changed. For a recent adventure of Jest debugging that led to a solution read my post:

> [Debugging Jest unit tests with breakpoints in VS Code with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056952/debugging-jest-unit-tests-with-breakpoints-in-vs-code-with-react-native/45073796#45073796)

In short it boils down to this:

1. Do **not** use NodeJS `v8.*` yet! This was the main problem. `inspector` protocol is not production-ready.

   - I downgraded from `8.1.2` to `7.10.1`
2. I used the Ignite CLI to bootstrap the project with the default `ignite-ir-boilerplate`

   - But you can use any boilerplate you want, if not using React Native or having different preferences. Most boilerplates generate source maps by default.
3. I used the Visual Studio Code debugger `v1.13.1` and then set the following configuration:

   ```
   {
       "type": "node",
       "request": "launch",
       "name": "Launch Tests",
       "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
       "args": [
           "--runInBand",
           "--no-cache"
       ],
       "runtimeArgs": [
           "--debug-brk=127.0.0.1:5858"
       ],
       "port": 5858
   }
   ```

That's it. You can set breakpoints in app code, node_modules and in your unit tests.