# Debugging React Native with Node shims in VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I have a React Native project (created from the Ignite CLI 2.0.0 default boilerplate) that needs some dependencies on node-based packages.

So, I created a `transformers.js`, `babel-transform.js` and a `rn-cli.js` according to [ReactNativify](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify). This is basically equivalent to what's in a normal `.babelrc` file and uses `babel-plugin-rewrite-require` to swap out Node objects and replace them either with Browserify shims, or empty mocks. So far, so good.

Now the problem is debugging this in Visual Studio Code (`1.13.1`). I've had a [significant adventure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45073796/8295283) (or horror story, if you will) with RN debugging already, but thought to have it running after downgrading Node to `7.10.1`.

Everything seems to go well, does halt on breakpoints, steps through code, etc., however this is the *actual* code not the transpiled output with the shims in place! Furthermore breakpoints open in a read-only code window that has no code indentation.

My debug configuration is:

```
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Tests",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
        "args": [
            "--runInBand",
            "--no-cache"
        ]
        // Not needed, but tried ;)
        //  "runtimeArgs": [
        //     "--debug-brk=127.0.0.1:5858"
        //  ],
        //  "port": 5858
    }
```

Does anyone have similar, hopefully better experience with this?

PS. There may be a [vscode github issue (#26782)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26782) related to this.

Comment: **PS** Those interested in using ReactNativify should beware of some issues, which I described in this SO answer: [Can we use nodejs code inside react native application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629856/can-we-use-nodejs-code-inside-react-native-application/45207249#45207249)

Comment: **Note**: Shimming was not viable, now looking into [Viable options for running NodeJS on Android (Aug 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649995/8295283)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my question I bumped into 2 problems.

The first one, tests performing against actual code, appeared to be an issue with Jest. The Jest team stated:

> *This is the expected behavior. Jest is supposed to run on source files. On any large codebase, generating a bundle before running tests is too slow, so Jest compiles files just-in-time, which makes it fast.*

Now this is probably a miscommunication and you can use it with proper `babel-jest` configuration to do dynamic transforms, I did not receive further help from the team. So I decided to go for a different test platform (either Mocha, Jasmine and/or Karma).

If you want to try your luck with Jest you can follow up on this thread: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4028

The second problem, code opening in a read-only panel in VS during debugging sessions, is an open issue being processed by Microsoft. You can check progress here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26782

[**Update**: I just received further instruction from the Jest team:

> @aschrijver the general way Jest handles this is by doing the transpilation itself. So you set up transformers in your config that Jest itself uses to do the transpilation.
>
> https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#transform-object-string-string
>
> An example config for Typescript is here to give you an idea of what this could look like: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest
>
> In terms of shims, what I think you might be wanting are actually Jest mocks. A Jest mock can step in instead of an actual module when you import or require it.

]